# input past end of file - vb.net application when opening csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

In my VB.net application, I am opening a `.csv` file to read its contents:

```
FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)

While NOT EOF(1)
    ...do code here
End While
```

it works perfectly, but there are some files I am having issues with. It keeps displaying an error saying `Input past end of file`

I tried adding `If NOT EOF(1)` inside and outside my while loop to test for the end of the file but its still displaying the same error message

Comment: Do the files which present the problem have a blank line at the end?

Comment: The Intellisense for those legacy BASIC file methods warns that you might be better off using the file IO methods in the My namespace.

Comment: No blank lines, it's happening half way through the first line it's reading in

Comment: @charlie It would be better if you showed us the code where the error happens, and a sample of data where it goes wrong (please anonymise the data if necessary). You might want to read about how to create a [mcve].